# Unipotent elements in a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, unipotent-matrices

In a matrix Lie group $G$, we say that $g\in G$ is unipotent if 
$$(g-I)^n=0 $$
for some $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

I read in a Tao's article, that

> More generally, we say that an element g of a Lie group $G$ is
>   unipotent if its adjoint action $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ on the Lie
>   algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is unipotent.

How can I show that in the matrix Lie group case these definition coincides, i.e., if $(g-I)^n=0$, then $(Ad_g(x)-x)^k =0$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ in the Lie algebra of $G$?

Is this even true?